# What do you add to a word to make it cute?

Tags: порядок-слов

In Spanish you add "-ito/a" as in hermanita, meaning little sister.  In English we mostly do this with modifier words like that ("little").

What is the common construct in Russian?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Russian this effect is achieved mainly by adding so-called diminutive suffixes to nouns. "Little sister" is Russian will be `сестричка` whereas `сестра` is a normal form. Here the `ичк` suffix is used, but in fact there are plenty of them. Seems difficult to remember them all for Russian learners. You can check out the whole list [here](http://tutrus.com/morfemika/suffiksy-imen-sushhestvitelnyx). There's a table with different suffixes on the page. See those which are below the title `Уменьшительно-ласкательные`.

Comment: Is that article a bit outdated? Nobody says `полосонька` now, everyone would say `полосочка`. Also, with names of people it doesn't work: many names have almost infinite amount of diminutive forms.

Comment: That's another good point.  I didn't consider that different types of nouns would have different suffixes.  What are common ones for names?

Comment: @TomSchober, different names may require different suffixes to be used with. Moreover, the same name can be combined with several suffixes producing different words with a diminutive accent. Off the top of my head I can say that `ечк` and `еньк` are the suffixes that are most commonly used for names. A few examples: `Ваня - Ванечка, Ванюша`, suffixes - `ечк` and `юш`; `Серёжа - Серёженька`, suffix - `еньк`; `Женя - Женечка`, suffix - `ечк`; `Маша - Машенька`, suffix - `еньк`. Seems to me that if the last consonant of a name is a hushing sound (`ж, ш`), `еньк` is used, otherwise, `ечк` is ok.

Answer (score 5):

чка and ик/чок, depending on gender.

Сестра -> сестричка.

Брат -> братик.

Кот -> котик.

Comment: You can read more about it here: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%D0%B8%D0%BA

Answer (score 2):

*it is not an answer to the question asked, just an illustration related to*

I remember such a series for `дурак` (a fool):

> *дурачок, дурашечка, дурашка*.
>   There’s even *дурачочек*.

A more important fact illustrated here is that combining such suffixes with a word may involve mutations of a pre-suffix consonant.

Answer (score 0):

As well, for a 'little sister' you could use:

> `сестрица` (often encountered in fairy tales)
>
> `сестрёночка` (derived from `сестрёнка`)
>
> `сеструха` (colloquial, denoting not only little, but sometimes also an older sister - context-dependent; note the spelling similarity to `старуха`)
>
> `сеструшечка` (derived from `сеструха`, note the spelling similarity to `старушечка` as well as to `ватрушечка`)

Pushing this to the extreme, you can create such little-used, but still understandable forms as:

> `сестричечка` (from `сестричка`)
>
> `сестричоночка` (similar to `мальчоночка`)
>
> `сестричушечка` (likely to be encountered in a verbal make-the-cutest-word contest)