# How to make -ичк form with мяч?

Tags: словоупотребление

I was wondering how to use the -ичк on the English word for 'ball(-y)' (cutesy form). Is it мячк?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's `мячик`, with `-ик` suffix.

See also [What do you add to a word to make it cute?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8588/what-do-you-add-to-a-word-to-make-it-cute)

Answer (score 2):

Actually I would argue that the masculine analogue of the -ичк suffix is -ишк, not -чик.

Thus:

мужик — мужичишка

заяц — зайчишка

холм — холмишко

сыч — сычишко

мяч — мячишко.

Symmetrically, the feminine form of -ик is -иц:

вода — водица

кобыла — кобылица

небыль — небылица

etc.